# Carregar js Externo com Meteor

Tags: meteor

Senhores, sou novo no meteor,...no meu projeto utilizo o bootbox.js pra abrir um prompt mais bonito, como eu faço referência a esse arquivo no meteor ? Tenho outros também

Desde de já muito obrigado a todos

Answer (score 0):

num projeto recém criado para esse teste ...

```
meteor create --bare teste
meteor npm install --save jquery bootstrap bootbox
```

em /client/main.html

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
```

em /client/main.js

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
window.$ = jQuery = require('jquery');
$(document).ready(() => {
  require('bootstrap');
  window.bootbox = require('bootbox');
  bootbox.alert("This is the default alert!");
});
```

abra o console do browser e teste os outros exemplos do site bootboxjs.com